# Calculating percent change between current value and value of a year ago R

Tags: r, grouping, percentage

Here is a sample of my dataframe:

```
A = data.frame(retailer = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
store = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), 
week = c(2021100301, 2021092601, 2021091901, 2021091201, 2021082901, 2021082201, 2021081501, 2021080801,
          2020100101, 2020092501, 2020091801, 2020091101, 2020090401, 2020082701, 2020082001, 2020081301),
dollars = c(121817.9, 367566.7, 507674.5, 421257.8, 453330.3, 607551.4, 462674.8,
  464329.1, 339342.3, 549271.5, 496720.1, 554858.7, 382675.5,
  373210.9, 422534.2, 381668.6),
final_week = c("20211040", "20211039", "20211038", "20211037", "20210935", "20210934", "20210933", "20210832", 
          "20201040", "20201039", "20201038", "20201037", "20200935", "20200934", "20200933", "20200832"),
fill = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

I have grouped these by retailer, then by store, and then by descending final_week value within each group. How can I find the percent difference in dollars between the most recent 4 final_week values and their corresponding final_week values from a year ago within each store grouping? For example, the first value in the final_week column is 20211040, which refers to year 2021. The value from a year ago would be 20201040 (year 2020). I would like to find the percent difference between these values, doing this for the four most recent final_week values (the first four per store groups as I have arranged them in descending order).

I've started by doing the following:

```
A = A %>%
group_by(retailer, store) %>%
arrange(arrange(retailer, store, desc(final_week), by_group = TRUE) %>%
```

but am not sure where to go from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've slightly modified your example data to have some useful result (one store, both years), here a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dyplr)
library(tidyr)

A %>%
  # add week and year
  mutate(year_ = substr(final_week, 1,4),
         week_ = substr(final_week,5,8)) %>%
  # remove useless columns
  select(-final_week,- week) %>%
  # from long to wide, with columns for years
  pivot_wider(names_from = year_,
              values_from = c(dollars)) %>%
   # get the last 4 weeks both years
   top_n(wt = week_,4) %>%
   # percentage
   mutate(perc = (`2021`- `2020`)/ `2020`*100)

# A tibble: 4 x 7
  retailer store  fill week_  `2021`  `2020`   perc
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1        2     5     1 1040  121818. 339342. -64.1 
2        2     5     1 1039  367567. 549272. -33.1 
3        2     5     1 1038  507674. 496720.   2.21
4        2     5     1 1037  421258. 554859. -24.1
```

EDIT:

Here a solution for years that can vary:

```
A %>%
  mutate(year_ = ifelse(substr(final_week,1,4) == min(substr(final_week,1,4)), 'first_y', 'second_y'),
         week_ = substr(final_week,5,8)) %>%
  select(-final_week,- week) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year_,
              values_from = c(dollars)) %>%
   top_n(wt = week_,4) %>%
   mutate(perc = (second_y - first_y)/ first_y*100)

  # A tibble: 4 x 7
  retailer store  fill week_ second_y first_y   perc
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1        2     5     1 1040   121818. 339342. -64.1 
2        2     5     1 1039   367567. 549272. -33.1 
3        2     5     1 1038   507674. 496720.   2.21
4        2     5     1 1037   421258. 554859. -24.1
```

---

With data

```
A <- data.frame(retailer = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
               store = rep(5,16), 
               week = c(2021100301, 2021092601, 2021091901, 2021091201, 2021082901, 2021082201, 2021081501, 2021080801,
                        2020100101, 2020092501, 2020091801, 2020091101, 2020090401, 2020082701, 2020082001, 2020081301),
               dollars = c(121817.9, 367566.7, 507674.5, 421257.8, 453330.3, 607551.4, 462674.8,
                           464329.1, 339342.3, 549271.5, 496720.1, 554858.7, 382675.5,
                           373210.9, 422534.2, 381668.6),
               final_week = c("20211040", "20211039", "20211038", "20211037", "20210935", "20210934", "20210933", "20210832", 
                              "20201040", "20201039", "20201038", "20201037", "20200935", "20200934", "20200933", "20200832"),
               fill = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
```

Comment: Hi, I see that you've put years 2021 and 2020 directly into the solution (in the last mutate line). My data gets refreshed every week so eventually it will reach years 2022 and so on so I would not be able to use the hardcoded years. Is there another way to find the difference between the most recent year and the year ago? (unless i am misunderstanding)

Comment: Hi, you're not misunderstanding. I think one solution could be going in another way than years and define a previous and a current, getting always the smaller and the bigger. See edit.